# How to cache http.Response in golang?

Tags: http, caching, go

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)
req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{Name: "c", Value: "ccc"})
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

I need to cache resp on disk and keep its type as http.Response after restoring from cache.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try some programming here? Or do you expect to find some package with magical `func DumpResponse(filename string) error` and `func Loadesponse(filename string) (*http.Response, error)`?

Comment: @Volker I'm asking for ideas, not ready made package.

Comment: convert `resp` to a `byte` array and write to a file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372227/go-conversion-between-struct-and-byte-array

Comment: Don't forget the headers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [httputil.DumpResponse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse) and [http.ReadResponse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse).

[See here for an example](http://play.golang.org/p/y6qIPwNVon). (You have to copy the code onto your local machine and run it there, because the Playground doesn't allow I/O)

The first dumps your request as-received, optionally also dumping the body, to an in-memory []byte that you can then write to disk. Later you can read the response back from disk (or where ever you stored it) and wrap it in an bufio.Reader, which you pass to http.ReadResponse.

ReadResponse takes a *http.Request as second parameter that is used as the value for the Request field of the response. If nil is given, the returned Response will have GET request in it's Request field.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

... Or use https://github.com/lox/httpcache. An RFC7234 compliant golang http.Handler for caching HTTP responses

Comment: Unchanged since 2017 and archived since 2021. "This repository has been archived by the owner on Apr 18, 2021. It is now read-only."

Comment: https://github.com/victorspringer/http-cache could be another solution which is not archived as of early 2024