# casting overlapping structs in golang

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and trying to figure out the correct way of casting a block of bytes to the correct struct. All structs start with two bytes that dictate the layout of the remaining bytes. In C I would point to the beginning of the block of memory and cast it as a simple struct that only contained those two bytes (X below) but here I get an invalid type assertion. I'm probably way off base here any help you be appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    tag   byte
    ver   byte
    data1 int
    data2 int
    data3 int
}

type B struct {
    tag   byte
    ver   byte
    data1 float32
}

type X struct {
    tag byte
    ver byte
}

func main() {
    var a A
    a.tag = 1
    a.ver = 1
    x := a.(X)

    fmt.Printf("%d,%d", x.tag, x.ver)
}
```

---

### Edit

In short I just want to create a custom method on type `Foo` that is the only reason why I want to perform the cast. If the solutions are very complex I will just create functions instead of methods I guess. I was just curios.

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/jDMXrmNESa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go conversion between struct and byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372227/go-conversion-between-struct-and-byte-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. It involves a few different tips:

1. **Embed** the shared struct in the individual structs.
2. Use `encoding/binary` package to load bytes into structs.
3. Fill header struct with first two bytes, then make a decision on which subtype to make and fill.
4. Always use fixed length int types for this kind of thing.
5. Your field names must be `UpperCase` to be fillable from `encoding/binary`
6. This is a pretty brittle way to manage marshalling.unmarshalling of data, but I'm sure you know that.

Here's my solution:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type A struct {
    X
    Data1 int32
    Data2 int32
    Data3 int32
}

type B struct {
    X
    Data1 int32
}

type X struct {
    Tag byte
    Ver byte
}

func main() {
    var err error
    data := []byte{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 42}
    hdr := X{}

    err = binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(data[:2]), binary.BigEndian, &hdr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hdr.Tag, hdr.Ver)

    if hdr.Tag == 1 {
        b := B{}
        err = binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(data), binary.BigEndian, &b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(b.Data1)
    }

}
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/4Djx9UYTLF)

Answer (score 1):

Go generally tries to discourage C-like memory fiddling as it leads to memory leaks, incorrect behavior, and security vulnerabilities unless extraordinary caution and testing are applied. That doesn't mean it's impossible though; in fact, the aptly-named [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) is exposed for exactly this purpose. Use it with caution.

Comment: `unsafe.Pointer` is probably not needed for this. `encoding/binary` can do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372227/go-conversion-between-struct-and-byte-array. But I do agree with your general warnings.